# Weak forms of HAVE

Tags: pronunciation, pronouns, contractions, have, weak-forms

According to Longman Pronunciation Dictionary

> **HAVE**: The weak form /v/ is used only after a vowel (when it is often written as the contraction *’ve*), or in very fast speech at the
> beginning of a sentence.
>
> Weak forms of *have, has, had* are used
> when the word is the equivalent of *have got* and is used with an
> object that is not a pronoun.

What does *object that is not a pronoun* exactly mean, and why does it not license a weak form?

Comment: I'm not sure I've got that.  Can you explain it better?

Comment: It _licenses_ a weak form. _I've a young son waiting to see me._ // But *_She's him right where she wants him_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why can¡t they license a weak form then?

Comment: More pertinently, why haven't you corrected the question? // Probably because stress is required on _She **has**_ ... or _She's **got**_ .... Compare *_Jill has more shoes than I've._ And note that the stressed form _Because, unlike Tim, **I have** a young son waiting to see me_ is available if needed.

Answer (score 1):

An "object that is not a pronoun" is an object of the verb that is not a pronoun. It's usually a noun or a noun phrase:

> I've **her concert tickets** here,
> I've **the things you wanted** in the trunk of my car.

but it could be other parts of speech as well. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#English).

Why does a pronoun prevent a weak form?

Probably because pronouns are typically not stressed, and English doesn't like putting too many unstressed words in a row. So if your object is stressed:

> I've **three** **tick**ets to the **con**cert,

you can leave *have* unstressed, and this lets you use the weak form instead of the full pronunciation. But if you use a pronoun, it's generally unstressed, and that automatically puts some stress on *have*:

> I **have** her **und**er sur**veil**lance.

(Note that the rules about stress in English are more complicated than what I've explained above, and that the stresses I've indicated aren't the only way of stressing the words in these sentences.)